# Is there a way to write a cell array with fprintf?

Tags: matlab

I have a variable (`strings`) that contains 192x14 cell array. I want to write this table into a text file. When I use `fprintf`, it says that "Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

For example:

```matlab
strings = {'foo','bar','baz'};
fprintf('%s ',strings);
```

produces the error message

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

Is there any other function that can do the trick?

Comment: @CrisLuengo `fprintf('%s\n', cellarray)` produces the error the OP mentioned (at least in R2018b). However, `fprintf('%s\n', cellarray{:})` does print the elements of the cell array one per line.

Comment: @JAC I stand corrected. Why not write up an answer then?

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Thanks for the suggestion. I did as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error try
`fprintf('%s\n', cellarray{:});`
that will write the elements of `callarray` one per line